# Weighted-random probability

Tags: probability

I'm a computer scientist and my mathematical knowledge is lacking. I asked a similar question on stack overflow but was told to ask here instead.

I have a list of percentages, which are ordered in descending order. I would like to choose one of these numbers, with an extreme likelihood of it being the first one, then decreasing likelihood for each item, until the final one is close to 0% chance of it being the final item in the list.

The list can contain anything number of percentages, possibly into the hundreds of thousands.

I am doing this in Java, so any recommendations of particular libraries or functions are preferred but any assistance would be great.

Comment: Note:  it is not clear from your question whether you want the values of the numbers to alter the probabilities.  I have posted something below which only takes the position into account (the values of the numbers are ignored entirely, only the position matters).  If that was not your intent, perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: What meaning has the value (percentage) of the row for your question please? It isn't clear from your post.

Comment: Hoacin - it's rather niche. Simply put the percentages rate the fitness of solutions to another problem, so one solution might be a 99.7% fit, another solution might be 96.5%. Using an evolutionary algorithm, I want to introduce a level of stochasticity so that my solution is not deterministic and allow exploration of an extremely large solution space.

Comment: Lulu - You are correct, the numbers should be ignored, it's the position which is important.

Comment: Now I understand it even less, wish you find good answer soon. My first idea was you maybe want to find some function like 0.9^row (descending slowly from 1 to 0), then sum all these variables, divide each with this sum and pick random one using way from Ethan Bolker's answer, but maybe you look for completely different thing. I used this approach many times, it just takes time to find f(row) function that descens in way you like.

Comment: Note;  if you want a comment to reach a specific user you need to include the @ symbol, as in @KenReid .  If you agree with my interpretation of the problem, do you agree that my posted solution gets the job done?  If not, what properties does my solution lack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have $k$ numbers.  Let $p_i$ denote the probability of choosing the number in slot $i$.  Of course $$\sum_{j=1}^kp_j=1$$

For simplicity, let's assume the $p_i$ decay geometrically.  That is, we assume there is some $r$ with $0<r<1$ such that $p_i=pr^{i-1}$ for all $i$.  Pick $p=p_1$ as you like. Then you just need to solve for $r$.

For example:  say we have $100$ numbers and that we want $p=p_1$ to be $\frac 12$.  We then remark that $$1=\frac 12\sum_{j=1}^{100} r^{j-1}\implies 2 = \frac {r^{100}-1}{r-1}\implies  r\approx \frac 12$$

If, instead, you preferred that $p=p_1=\frac 34$ then you would get $r\approx \frac 14$.

If you are willing to assume that $k$ is very large then the calculation simplifies as you can approximate the finite sum by the infinite geometric sum.  We'd then get $$\frac 1p\approx \frac 1{1-r}\implies r\approx 1-p$$  Note that our examples illustrate this approximation, even for $k=100$.

Comment: Note to OP. Here's how to choose from this distribution. http://home.apache.org/~luc/commons-math-3.6-RC2-site/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.distribution/GeometricDistribution.java.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want the probability of choosing a number to be its percentage.

The following algorithm assumes that the list is given once and the choices made repeatedly.

Suppose you start with the list

> 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1

Create a list of the partial sums

> 0.4 0.7 0.9 (1.0)

You have to do that just once.

Now repeatedly choose a random number $r$ between $0$ and $1$ and see where $r$ falls in the list of partial sums - binary search will do that quickly.

This is straightforward in Java.

Comment: Not quite, the position is more important than the value of the percentage. It's possible that the values could be as low as 0.1%, or as high as 99.9%. 

Additionally the percentages would not add up to 100%, they are more likely to look like 0.9, 0.89, 0.89, 0.88, etc. 

Thank you for your assistance.